# Democratic values. Does it require the definite article?

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

I've read in Practical English Grammar that you don't usually put the definite article in front of so-called "half-general expressions". Is "Democratic values" in that category? Or does it require the definite article?

I'm sure I should say "The values of Democracy"

But is it "Democratic values" or "The democratic values"?

Is there a rule of thumb that can help see where not to use the definite article?

An example sentence:

> "It doesn't matter that {blank} says that it adheres to (the ?)
>   democratic values. It's still an autocracy."

Comment: "Values" is uncountable in this context. So it would not have the article.

Comment: @Weather The definite article can easily be put in front of uncountable nouns, like in "pass me the salt". Values here is plural and synonymous to beliefs.

Comment: That is a shortening of "Pass me the salt cellar." It is still "sth adheres to  democratic values" unless it goes on: "We adhere to the democratric values which we learnt at college."